# Ayuda para comparar objetos Json en Java y obtener un Json de diferencias!

Tags: java, json

Tengo la siguiente función que me genera un Json con todos los contenidos de un directorio:

```
  public static void generateReport(File dir, JSONArray content) throws IOException, ParseException {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        String md5;
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                content.add(obj);
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    md5 = md5OfString(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    obj.put("md5", md5);
                    obj.put("type", "folder");
                    obj.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    JSONArray contentSon = new JSONArray();
                    obj.put("Content", contentSon);
                    generateReport(listFile[i], contentSon);
                    //numDir++;
                } else if (listFile[i].isFile()) {
                    md5 = md5OfFile(listFile[i]);
                    obj.put("md5", md5);
                    obj.put("type", "file");
                    obj.put("path", listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    //numFiles++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Llamando dos veces a esta función, con parametros diferentes, generaría dos JSON con diferentes datos. Lo que necesito es comparar ambos JSON generados y generar un nuevo JSON con las diferencias entre los otros dos.

Ej de reporte de diferencias:

```
{
    "root": "/u/data/Coldview/apps",
    "origin-report": "informe.json",
    "diff": [
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos",
            "origin-md5": ".........",
            "destination-md5": "........."
        },
        {
            "type": "folder",
            "path": "ldf.web.ejecuciondeprotestos/lib",
            "origin-md5": ".........",
            "destination-md5": "........."
        },
        {
            "type": "file", 
            "name": "AMCOX.Core.jar", 
            "origin-md5": ".........",
            "destination-md5": "........."
        }
    ]
}
```

Lo que no sé es como comparar mis dos objetos JSON y obtener las diferencias entre ambos.

Estoy usando la librería Json-Simple

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

pero no parece tener ningún método para lo que necesito por lo que estoy viendo si tengo que cambiar de librería o que !

Gracias por la ayuda, consejos, etc.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que hice y que funciona de maravillas es leer ambos objetos en HashMap y luego compararlos con un assertEquals () regular. Llamará al método equals () de los hashmaps, que comparará recursivamente todos los objetos que están dentro (serán otros hashmaps o algún objeto de valor único como una cadena o un entero). Esto se hizo usando el Codehaus' Jackson JSON parser...

```
assertEquals (mapper.readValue (expectedJson, new TypeReference <HashMap <String, Object >> () {}), mapper.readValue (actualJson, nueva TypeReference <HashMap <String, Object >> () {}));
```

Se puede usar un enfoque similar si el objeto JSON es una matriz en su lugar.

Comment: Un poco más de info para poder googlear ??